# How to use multiple criteria.add(restrictions)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Can i use multiple criteria.add ? In the case i want to

```
public ArrayList<Support> SearchSupportby(int appId ,String unikey,Timestamp formDate ,) {
     Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Support.class, "support");
     if(unikey!=null) {
     criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("support.uuId",unikey));
     }
     if(appId!=null){
     criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("support.applicationId",appId));
     }
     if(formdate!=null){
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("support.reportDate", formDate));
     }
}
```

It may help.I use

Spring boot 1.2.5

Hibernate 4.3.6

***After Change to use JPA I just know the easy way

```
Conjunction objConjunction = Restrictions.conjunction(); 
objConjunction.add(Restrictions **your Query A **  );
objConjunction.add(Restrictions **your Query B **  );
objConjunction.add(Restrictions **your Query C **  );
criteria.add(objConjunction);
```

Comment: You spring data jpa instead of Hibernate explicitly. You can use multiple add multiple criteria.add() but if you using spring boot no need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have shared multiple criteria using hibernate creations. you can validate accordingly, as I am expecting all parameters.

```
public List<Support> SearchSupportby(int appId ,String unikey,Timestamp formDate ,) {
 Criteria cr = getSession().createCriteria(Support.class, "support");
 Criterion rest1 = Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("support.uuId",unikey));
 Criterion rest2 = Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("support.applicationId",appId));
 Criterion rest3 = Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("support.reportDate", formDate));
 cr.add(Restrictions.and(rest1, rest2, rest3));//according to parameter you can validate it
 cr.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
 if (cr.list() == null || cr.list().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
return cr.list();}
```

Answer (score 0):

You spring data jpa instead of Hibernate explicitly. You can use multiple add multiple criteria.add() but if you using spring boot no need to do it manually.

You can define repository for Support entity by extending JpaRepository.

```
interface SupportRepository extends JpaRepository<Support,Long>{

}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

You can use **Specification** for having multiple conditions. 
https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-four-jpa-criteria-queries/